# Induction on two integer variables

Tags: induction

Assume you want to prove an identity such as

$$\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}A(k,m)-B(k,m)=S(m)+T(n,m)\qquad\text{for } n,m\in 
\mathbb{Z},n,m\geq 0.$$

*Added*: I applied mathematical induction on $m,n$ to prove it. I am unsure because up to now I have seen it applied to properties depending on a single variable only.

Question: does application of two inductive arguments, one on $m$ and the
other on $n$, guarantee the validity of such a proof?

Comment: Sure.  Why wouldn't it?

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: Thanks! I asked it because I actually have not seen yet any proof of a two indices identity by this method.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here are some induction principles for two variables:

- $P(0,0)$
- $\forall x,y. P(x,y) \Rightarrow P(x+1,y)$
- $\forall x,y. P(x,y) \Rightarrow P(x,y+1)$

  ---
- $\forall x,y. P(x,y)$

and

- $P(0,0)$
- $\forall x,y. P(x,0) \Rightarrow P(x+1,0)$
- $\forall x,y. P(x+1,y) \Rightarrow P(x,y+1)$

  ---
- $\forall x,y. P(x,y)$

Comment: @muad: in the 2nd example is it  $\forall x,y. P(x+1,y) \Rightarrow P(x,y+1)$  or  $\forall x,y. P(x,y) \Rightarrow P(x,y+1)$?

Comment: @Américo Tavares, the second one is covering the x-axis and shifting diagonally back to cover everything above it. So it is $\forall x,y. P(x+1,y) \Rightarrow P(x,y+1)$.

Comment: Nice! You can extend this to transfinite ordinals by taking 

$$\forall z\Big(\big(\forall x,y\big[x<y\Rightarrow P(x,z)\big]\big)\Rightarrow P(y,z)\Big),$$

 and 

$$\forall z\Big(\big(\forall x,y\big[x<y\Rightarrow P(z,x)\big]\big)\Rightarrow P(z,y)\Big).$$

Answer (score 19):

Suppose you are trying to prove a family of statements $P(x, y)$.  This is the same as proving the family of statements $F(x)$, where $F(x) = \forall y : P(x, y)$.  Each statement $F(x)$ can be proven by induction on $y$ (for fixed $x$), and then you can prove $P(x, y)$ by induction on $x$.  You might want to try proving

$${n+1 \choose k+1} = {n \choose k+1} + {n \choose k}$$

this way.

But actually you can be much trickier than this.  Sometimes it suffices to induct on $x + y$, for example.